# Cant destroy oak button

Tags: java, minecraft

When I click onto an oak button, it want to destroy the oak button and the coal block below. But instead, this happens:

[image: minecraft image]

Also, `getDrops().clear()` doesn't work, as there still are drops.

Here's my code:

```
package me.doshicshow.mycustomitems;

import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.bukkit.event.block.BlockPlaceEvent;
import org.bukkit.block.BlockFace;
import org.bukkit.block.Block;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Customitems extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("Minecraft");
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
        if (event.getClickedBlock() != null && event.getClickedBlock().getType() == Material.OAK_BUTTON && event.getClickedBlock().getRelative(BlockFace.DOWN).getType() == Material.COAL_BLOCK) {
            log.info(String.format("Found object %s", event.getClickedBlock()));
            event.getClickedBlock().breakNaturally();
            event.getClickedBlock().getDrops().clear();
            event.getClickedBlock().getRelative(BlockFace.DOWN).getDrops().clear();
            event.getClickedBlock().getRelative(BlockFace.DOWN).breakNaturally();
        }
    }
}
```

It should destroy the oak button and the coal (the coal doesn't need to drop anything). What could I do to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried cancelling the event? This will remove the interaction animation, and destroy your block instantly. This might be a solution if you really just want it gone - and not get all that fancy animation stuff :)

Comment: how? I'm very new to plugins and java

Comment: Cancelling the event works with `event.setCancelled(true)`, then you can remove the block. Just do a quick google how that works :)